# Error on php mongodb client with more tha 500K updates

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, debian

I use php mongo db client in Debian

PHP 8.2.6
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Sometimes while updating 500k documents the process stops with the error

/build/php-mongodb-1.15.0+1.11.1+1.9.2+1.7.5/build-8.2/src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-buffer.c:139 _mongoc_buffer_append(): precondition failed: (buffer->datalen + data_size) < INT_MAX

```php
         $manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');           
         $bulk = new \MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(array("ordered" => false));

         while (is_object($richiesta = $richieste->fetch_object())) {
               ...
               $bulk->update(
                 array('_id'=>$dati['id_mov_contab']),
                 $aXML,
                 array('multi' => false, 'upsert' => true)
               );
         }
         ...
         if($bulk->count()>0) {
             $manager->executeBulkWrite('catasto.catasto', $bulk);
         }
```

If I limit the dataset al 200k per time if works.

I tried to periodically execute the bulk write, without success.

```php
         $manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');           
         $bulk = new \MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(array("ordered" => false));
         
         $c=0;
         while (is_object($richiesta = $richieste->fetch_object())) {
               ...
               $bulk->update(
                 array('_id'=>$dati['id_mov_contab']),
                 $aXML,
                 array('multi' => false, 'upsert' => true)
               );
               if($c%1e6 ==0 && $bulk->count()>0 ) {
                   $manager->executeBulkWrite('catasto.catasto', $bulk);
                   $manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');           
                   $bulk = new \MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(array("ordered" => false));
               }
               $c++;
         }
         ...
         if($bulk->count()>0) {
             $manager->executeBulkWrite('catasto.catasto', $bulk);
         }
```

Comment: Where did `$count` come from, and where is `$c` used?

Comment: Sorry ... a wrong copy and paste.